# How to make a large mysql database capable of fast operations

Tags: mysql, database, web

I'm going to make a mysql database that is potentially going to hold thousands of records. before I create it I would like know what is the best way to approach this? I mean how can I make the database faster and when does a mysql databse start to slow down when fetching data.
Are there any free solutions to this?

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thousands of records is absolutely nothing for a DB.

Make proper indexes on the column you like to put conditions on in your queries. Example database table:

```
Persons
------------------------------
id      int auto_increment
name    varchar(200)
gender  char(1)
```

Now imagine in the table are thousands of Person records. You want to select all data of a single person by the person's name.

The query would be

```
select * from persons
where name = 'John'
```

If you put an index on the `name` column then the query will perform much faster.

Comment: I kind of a newbie in the whole database area and i don't really know what it means to index a database or how to do it. If you could provide an example of and indexed database it would be really helpful. I'm assuming indexing does not mean to simply put a number next on each row.

Comment: I updated my answer, but you really should read up on indexes. I can't really explain it in a few sentences. See [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) for instance.